# Does a PCI card IO address and IRQ change if I remove other PCI cards?

Tags: pci

So I plugged in a PCI card and know from the OS that the IO range is e400-e4f1 and the IRQ is 5. Will this change if I unplug other PCI cards from the same computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually they do change.

**edit**: e400-e4f1 changed to c400-c4f1 when adding another card.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter if you're using a modern OS that supports Plug and Play. It should be able to detect the device properly at boot time, even if it has been moved to a different slot. If it doesn't, you can always put the cards back the way they were.

Comment: No I'm not using a modern operating system.

Comment: @slipbull: "modern" in this case means pretty much anything after Win98.  (it might even mean "Win95 or later" but i can't bring myself to admit that.)  what are you running?

Comment: QNX4 -hate the 15 character minimum in comments-